# Determine column data types in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, shell, command-line

I'm interacting with a PostgreSQL on command-line based environment, and I'd like to be able to determine the data types of the table columns in this database.

For a simple example, when I request

`SELECT * FROM products`

I'd like to know if the `product id` column it returns is giving me text or integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this kind of information by querying the catalog.

To find the specific queries, run `psql -E` (to echo hidden query) and then e.g. `\d products`. You'll see psql output various queries that yield information about your table, its column types, indexes, etc.

In this specific case, you'd run something like:

```
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = 'products'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

Comment: Thanks! `\d products` worked for me, but I didn't understand the code you posted...